# IIS Self Signed Certificate Works local network but not internet

Tags: ssl, iis, https, certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows Server 2008 - R2 with IIS 7 that when I try t local I acces using like: http://192.168.0.10 and when I'm over the internet, I use the IP the my internet provider gives to me (http://200.195.30.5 , for example).
I installed a self signed certificade on IIS 7 and bind it.
Its working like a charm for https://192.168.0.10, but https://200.195.30.5 isn't, I got time out.
Is there anything that I could be missing? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is port 443 forwarded to the internal IP of the IIS server? This sounds like a networking issue if you are getting a timeout and not an SSL error.

Comment: The problem was with port forward, indeed. It's working now. Thank you!